# Strange voltage reading on ungrounded system

Tags: solar-cell, inverter

On a small scale off-grid PV project I received a strange voltage reading and I am hoping that some folks here could possibly shed some more light on what exactly was going on and why. Here is the background:

- 375W pure sine wave inverter outputting 220V.
- Ungrounded system
- I have left out all other extraneous details and circuits from the attached drawing.
- One lighting circuit that that was roughly 100m in length with a switch controlling four lights.
- With the switch open and no bulbs in the sockets I received a voltage measurement of roughly 28V. I understand that on an ungrounded system with no bulbs in the socket and an open switch the length of wire that I was taking a voltage measurement to effectively had no reference to the system.

My questions:

- why 28V? Why not 0?
- Can you steer me in the right direction to be able to understand this better?

[image: simple drawing of system/issue]

Comment: how far is the switch from the measurement point, and how far the end of the cable?

Comment: The switch is roughly 90 meters from the inverter and 12 meters from the light. it is not exactly as pictured in the diagram as it is cut into the positive and drops down a wall.

Comment: wow, that's 90 meters of coupling, and antenna length. No wonder! Laptop2d's answer is on spot!

Comment: If it is acting as an antenna, is it actually picking up the field from the AC that is running on the other wire or is it picking up something else altogether?

Comment: see laptop2d's answer.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the neutral side of the inverter is still connected to the bulb from your diagram.

First off AC can travel across conductors and through air because there is a small amount of capacitance between, this turns parts of the circuit that are floating into something like an antenna.

If I plug my meter into the hot side (120V) of an outlet and let the other end wave in the air, I get a measurement of roughly 14-28V because the other probe functions something like an antenna. Something similar could be happening in your case because volt meters can detect very small currents, but impossible to say exactly what without knowing all the details of your setup.

This is one of the reasons to have a ground, so you have something to reference voltages to. Floating pieces of metal (like the disconnected portion of your circuit) make bad references to make voltage measurements. A good idea would be to string a long cable back to the chassis of the inverter so you have something to reference to, or ground your system.

Comment: I just played around with my multimeter, which is a quality multimeter and your answer does coincide with my results, but I cannot say that I still quite understand why - could you elaborate any more on the antenna explanation further? Here are a few other random details: 1. The voltage reading varies from person to person in my office if they grab the probe from 38V-98V. 2. Whether you have shoes on or not significantly affects the voltage by as much as 50V. 3. Whether the power strip is on or off the results are the same, but if the probes are out of the powerstrip they change.

Comment: You've built an antenna. Antennas "fish" energy out of thin air. Your multimeter is a sensor for energy.

Comment: @AlexJ. 1) Even with the outlet strip off, one side might still be on. 2) Even if both sides were off there is a non negligible amount (small values) of inductance and capacitance between metal conductors. AC loves to travel through inductors and capacitors

Comment: @laptop2d Thanks for your answer. Your first answer was spot on, but it took me a bit of self education to fully grasp it.

Comment: @AlexJ. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126180/is-it-acceptable-to-write-a-thank-you-in-a-comment